# CLI Struct Array

Tags: arrays, command-line-interface, marshalling

I have tried just about everything that I can think of to make the below work. I am trying to pass in a Array of a Cli struct into a CLI method and have that CLI method execute a c++ Method, the c++ method access a pointer of a class and that pointer is a array of the class.

I was able to marshal correctly when I only sent in a single Struct, so before I made it an array. But as as array I do not know how to get it to work. Everything I've tried always fails as soon as I try to get a pointer of the CLI or reinterpret_cast the CLI array.

Please note that the below is not the actual code, it's a copy paste/edit of the actual code as I cannot upload the original code due to NDA's I have signed...

```
// Not the actual CLI object, but a good reference and the actual CLI and original struct do work, tested...
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, CharSet = CharSet::Ansi, Pack = 2)]
public ref struct CliExample{
    int Number;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    String ^Description;
};

// CLI Code
long GetValue(List<CliExample^>^% Recs, long NoOfRecs)
{
    IntPtr ListPtr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(Marshal::SizeOf(Recs));
    Marshal::StructureToPtr(Recs, ListPtr, false);

    Server->GetValue(reinterpret_cast<tExample*>(ListPtr.ToPointer()),NoOfRecs);
}

// Snippet of c++ code
long tLaunch::GetValue(tExample* Recs, long NoOfRecs)
{
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work, an NDA prevents me from telling you why.  There just isn't any point to it, you already have the native type (tExample).  Call the native code with a properly sized tExample[] and simply copy the returned data to the list.  One field at a time, not a struct at a time.  Trying to use Marshal::PtrToStructure() will get you into trouble when the marshaller tries to release the returned strings.  You'll have to do that yourself, whatever is appropriate for the native code.

Comment: lol @ your comment, "nda prevents" :P I only mentioned that because some clever people will always comment saying the code is incomplete etc... or mention the typos will cause compile errors...

Thanks for the help though, I will just copy each struct one at a time as you mentioned.